# Vim autocmd (save file, run code formatter, reload file)

Tags: vim, uncrustify

I wish to integrate the source code formatter [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) with Vim. Any of the below two options will suffice.

1. Format the code that I am currently editing (i.e. when `gq` is pressed).
2. Format the code when I save the file and then reload the formatted file into current Vim window.

Option 1 is preferable. I tried

```
set formatprg=uncrustify\ -c ~/misc/uncrustify.cfg --no-backup
```

i.e. I call Uncrustify with command line options.
This does not work. Vi gives the `E518: Unknown option: ~/misc/uncrustify.cfg` error.

For option 2, I tried the following in the vimrc file

```
autocmd bufwritepost *.cpp ! ~/bin/uncrustify -c ~/misc/uncrustify.cfg --no-backup <afile>
```

The file is formatted after the save, but I have to manually reload the file into Vim.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried escaping whitespaces:

`:set formatprg=uncrustify\ -c\ ~/misc/uncrustify.cfg\ --no-backup`

**UPDATE**

`uncrustify` prints "Parsing: 170 bytes ..." message to stderr so we need to redirect it to `/dev/null`:

`:set formatprg=uncrustify\ -c\ ~/misc/uncrustify.cfg\ -l\ CPP\ --no-backup\ 2>/dev/null`

`gq` operates on lines, so you can select necessary lines in visual mode and execute `gq`. For example, if you want to reformat whole file execute `ggVGgq`.

More info at `:help gq`

Comment: That removed the VI error. I also had to add the -l option to specify the language as CPP, since input to uncrustify is from stdin. However, pressing gq in vi does not format the file. If I press it again, then the only the current line is formatted and the following line is added to the file being edited - "Parsing: 57 bytes (57 chars) from stdin as language CPP " . I think what I am missing is how to configure the formatprg command to read the entire file, and secondly prevent output of the above line to the file being edited.